# DataContext.SubmitChanges timeout with strange stack trace

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

My big, two-year long project just went live two weeks ago.  While we've had the normal launch issues, it's been pretty successful, except for one strange error that has reared its head.

This story has been changed; the actual project has nothing to do with movie tickets.

Our site allows employees at movie theaters to print movie tickets.  Once they've decided what they want to print, they go to the print-tickets web page and click 'print'.  This sends a batch of data to the movie ticket printer and a few seconds later the user's ticket printer starts pumping out tickets.

We number the tickets, and want to make sure that no duplicate numbers are used.  The code to do it looks like this:

```
using (TicketContext context = new TicketContext(ConnectionString)) {

    // call a stored proc that allocates a group of tickets with fancy transaction stuff

    var result = context.GetNextTicketGroup(tickets.Count).FirstOrDefault();
    if (result == null || !result.Column1.HasValue || result.Column1.Value == -1)
        return "There was an error allocating ticket numbers";
    int ticketNumber = result.Column1.Value;

    // Put the ticket numbers in the ticket objects
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ticketCount; i++) {
        tickets[i].TicketNumber = ticketNumber + i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ticketCount; i++) {
        // Convert the ticket object that we've been working with into 
        // a record that is the kind we have in the database and 
        // put that into the database.  CreateTicket() doesn't do any 
        // database stuff directly.
        DBTicket newticket = CreateTicket(ticket[i]); 
        context.Tickets.InsertOnSubmit(newticket);
    }
    // Each ticket is tied to an Issuance ID - Get a list of IssuanceIDs from the
    // list of tickets and mark them as printed
    var IDs = items.Select(id => id.IssuanceID).Distinct();
    foreach (Guid g in IDs) {
        var Issuance = context.TicketIssuances.Where(ti => ti.ID == g).FirstOrDefault();
        if(Issuance != null) {
            Issuance.Printed = true;
        }
    }

    // Submit the changes to the database
    context.SubmitChanges();

    // Send the printers to the ticket printer via a web service
    using (TicketService.TicketSoapClient ssc = new TicketService.TicketSoapClient()) {
        var a = tickets.ToArray();
        if (ssc.PrintTickets(a) == false)
            return "Error printing.";
    }
}   // LINE 392
```

Now, the unusual part is that `context.SubmitChanges()` times out, but the stack trace looks like this:

```
 [...]  
 at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item)
 at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
 at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
 at Portal.Tickets.PrintTickets.PrintTicketList(List`1 items) in d:\Source\PrintTickets.aspx.cs:line 392
 at Portal.Tickets.PrintTickets.btnPrintTickets_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Source\PrintTickets.aspx.cs:line 236
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I called out line 392 in the code above; note that it is at the point where the datacontext is going out of scope, well after the timeout should have happened.

These are small jobs that certainly wouldn't time out with out some sort of deadlock or something; we're only putting tens of records into the database at a time and the server is not under excessive load.  99%+ of our job submission go through just fine, it's only a tiny fraction that hit this error, but when they do, several of them hit it within a few minutes of each other. I'd be inclined to entirely blame the database server, except for the weird stack trace. Any insight?

Comment: Shouldn't the stack trace indicate line 384 (the call to SubmitChanges) not line 392, where the context goes out of scope?  And when it happened on Friday afternoon, the server did not appear to be under heavy load at the time.

Comment: The exception was the not-very-helpful "Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."  And we have production errors like this regularly, I've never seen the line number be incorrect before.  And that code hasn't moved line numbers in quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a race condition to a deadlock if there is a time out. What was the motivation for trying to increment some integer value as the unique ID for tickets instead of simply using a GUID? LINQ-to-SQL does offer some limited logging by setting the DataContext.Log property, but I don't know how useful/viable this would be in your production scenario.